# Comparing Long to simple integer in Java

Tags: java

I was writing a simple condition

```
List<Long> path = doSomething(); // returns a list of Long and all equal to -1
if (path.get(0)==-1)
    sysout("first condition works"); // never executes
if (path.get(0).equals(-1))
    sysout("sec condition works");  //never executes
if (path.get(0).equals(new Long(-1)))  
    sysout("third condition works");  //works!
```

**Why** is that? Please point me to some article in the official doc files to read more!

Comment: use -1L instead of -1?

Comment: Hint: `Long` is object.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Integer                       Long
  ^                            ^
  |                            |        auto-boxing/auto-unboxing
  |                            |
  v                            v
 int -----------------------> long

      primitive promotion
```

This schema shows what **implicit** conversions Java can do between different things.

In Java, objects and primitives are unfortunately different beasts: `Long` and `long` are not the same things. An implicit conversion from `long` to `Long` is called *auto-boxing*. An implicit conversion from `Long` to `long` is called *auto-unboxing*. This kind of conversion is descibed in [section 5.1.8 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8).

Also, like many other languages, Java has implicit conversions between numeric types. An `int` is implicitly promoted to a `long` if it is used in an expression that contains other `long`s. The contexts in which these promotions can occur are described in [section 5.6 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6).

Note that the literal `1` in Java has type `int`. The litteral `1L` has type `long`.

```
Long v = ...
if(v == -1) ...
```

`v` is a `Long` and `-1` is an `int`. Java does not know how to compare objects and primitives: it relies on its implicits conversions rules to do so. Here, `-1` is converted (auto-boxed) to an `Integer`. So, we are comparing the reference of two objects that don't even have the same type: the test fails.

```
Long v = ...
if(v.equals(-1)) ...
```

This is the same thing as above, except that it's not a comparision that triggers the implicit conversion, but a method call. `equals` takes an `Object` as a parameter, so `-1` is converted (auto-boxed) to an `Integer`. Implicit conversions triggered by method calls are described in [section 5.3 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3).

```
Long v = ...
if(v.equals(new Long(-1))) ...
```

Here, we call the `Long.equal` method with a `Long` as a parameter, so the test succeeds.

**What comparision works, then ?**

```
Long v = ...
if(v.equals(-1L)) ...
```

`-1L` is a `long`. It is passed to a method that expects an `Object`, so it is implicitly converted (auto-boxed) to a `Long`. The test succeeds.

```
Long v = ...
if(v.longValue() == -1) ...
```

`v.longValue()` is a `long`, `-1` is an `int`. `-1` is promoted to a `long` because of the `==` operator. The test succeeds.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you. Do you mind adding reference/s to your answer?

Comment: I'll try to do that soon, yes.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (path.get(0)!=null && path.get(0).longValue()==-1)
    System.out.println("first condition works");
```

If you compare `long` primitives you can use method [longValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#longValue%28%29).
However you should check `Long` object for `null` before calling this method.

Comment: Adding an explanation and a reference to `longValue()` will be very helpful to OP.

Comment: -1L is probably a better way to go as `.get(0)` could return null, then `.longValue()` would throw a NPE

Comment: You mean if (path.get(0).longValue()==-1L)

Answer (score 3):

Your two first cases are comparing a Long to an Integer (due to autoboxing), and they can never be the same object (naturally).

Your final case is the correct one. Use equals() when comparing objects.

EDIT: Or the longValue()/intValue() etc. methods if you want to use the == operator.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `if (path.get(0).equals(-1))`

with

```
if (path.get(0).equals(-1L))
```

By default, number is treated as Integer in java, and thus the comparison fails.

Take a look at [auto-boxing in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Because, `equals()` expects `Object`. You can't pass premitive value in `equals()` method. So, `equals(-1)` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  if (path.get(0).equals(-1)) //long value
```

Or

```
if (path.get(0).longValue()==-1)
```

Or

```
if (path.get(0)==-1L)
```